# Creating aliases for Github Copilot CLI (ghcs, ghce not recognised)

Tags: windows, powershell, github, command-line-interface, alias

I'm having an issue setting up aliases for github copilot.
`gh copilot suggest` and `gh copilot explain` work fine, I want to reduce them to `ghcs` and `ghce`.

When I run `ghcs "create new dir"` this is the error I get,

```
ghcs : The term 'ghcs' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ghcs "new dir"
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ghcs:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

**CONTEXT**
I use VSC with Powershell on Windows, also just downloaded the Microsoft's Powershell extension, but it didn't help.

On github's [manual page](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/github-copilot-in-the-cli/using-github-copilot-in-the-cli), they say it should be as simple as running this in the terminal `gh copilot alias`.

This created two files in my powershell folder:
[New Files in the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m67DL.png)

PS.
I've also tried to create a new powershell profile by `New-Item -Force $PROFILE` and copied this (this is what GH also suggested in their manual) `$GH_COPILOT_PROFILE = Join-Path -Path $(Split-Path -Path $PROFILE -Parent) -ChildPath "gh-copilot.ps1" gh copilot alias -- pwsh | Out-File ( New-Item -Path $GH_COPILOT_PROFILE -Force ) echo ". $GH_COPILOT_PROFILE" >> $PROFILE`, but still had no luck.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Where did you install?  Is the path part of environmental variable PSMODULEPATH.  Press Start and type Edit Environmental Variables For Your Account

Comment: do you get an error when you start powershell ? where it tries to load the functions ghcs and ghce and fails ?

Comment: @jdweng it looks like this could be a path issue. The .ps1 files were saved here: `C:\Users\arthu\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell`. I'm looking at the "Edit environment variable" and the PSMODULEPATH has two paths `%ProgramFiles%\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` and `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`. Do I simply update the path in PSMODULEPATH, so it matches with where the files are saved? Sorry, I'm a complete CLI noob. Appreciate your response!

Comment: @CaVaRT: Profile loading has nothing to do with `PSModulePath` or any other environment variable. Note that installing the PowerShell extension changes the value of `$PROFILE`, because the latter has its own profile. Loading of that profile may be _disabled_ via the extension's settings. After running the alias-installation code, you must either start a new session or run `. $PROFILE` to make the aliases take effect.

Comment: @ShehrozeMalik yes, I just bumped into it.
1. I added the code, which GitHub recommends for PS to my PS profile (which is in $profile)
2. I then run the `gh copilot alias`. It created those 2 new files in the PS profile folder. But says the `ghcs` is not recognised when I try run `ghcs`
3. If I kill the terminal and open again, this is what I get
```
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndCurlyBrace
```

Comment: @mklement0 thanks, I've disabled the profile loading. I ran `gh copilot alias` and started a new session, I got this error `Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
At \Documents\WindowsPowerShell\gh-copilot.ps1:59 char:15
+ function ghce {
+               ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At \Documents\WindowsPowerShell\gh-copilot.ps1:81 char:1
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndCurlyBrace`

Comment: The implication is that the PowerShell code in `gh-copilot.ps1` has a syntax error. You can create these "aliases" (`function`s in PowerShell) yourself: `function ghce { gh copilot explain @args }` and `function ghcs { gh copilot suggest @args }`

Comment: @jdweng, to avoid confusion, please stop mentioning the `PSModulePath` environment variable - which relates to _module loading_ only - in contexts where it doesn't apply, such as profile loading and discovery of external executables.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks so much! It has worked! For anyone with the same issue, I also had to remove the code Github suggested adding to the PS profile because it was overwriting the `gh-copilot.ps1` when I started a new session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- Run the alias-installation commands detailed [in the instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/github-copilot-in-the-cli/using-github-copilot-in-the-cli#setting-up-aliases-for-copilot-in-the-cli) *once*, in order to *programmatically update* your PowerShell `$PROFILE` file - do NOT add those instructions *themselves* to the latter.
- As of this writing, the generated "aliases" (which are actually wrapper *`function`s*) work in *[PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) only*. See below for a *Windows PowerShell* solution.

---

###### Current problems:

As of this writing, there are two problems with the [Copilot extension for `gh`, the GitHub CLI](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/github-copilot-in-the-cli/using-github-copilot-in-the-cli):

- `gh copilot alias -- pwsh` produces PowerShell code that works *in [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) only*; your symptom implies that you ran it from *Windows PowerShell*.

  - However, the code could easily be fixed to run in Windows PowerShell - see below.
  - See [GitHub issue #32189](https://github.com/github/docs/issues/32189).
- The [instructions for setting up aliases](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/github-copilot-in-the-cli/using-github-copilot-in-the-cli#setting-up-aliases-for-copilot-in-the-cli) are confusing:

  - The code shown is *setup code*, meant to be run *once* in order to *programmatically add* the "aliases" (which are actually *functions*) to the profile / initialization files of supported shells, whereas the instructions, e.g. "Add the following to your PowerShell profile:", mistakenly suggest that the setup code *itself* should be added to the profile / initialization file.
  - See [GitHub issue #32187](https://github.com/github/docs/issues/32187).

---

###### Installing *Windows PowerShell-compatible* aliases (functions):

Hopefully, the need for the following workarounds will go away, once the Copilot extension is updated to be compatible with Windows PowerShell too - once that has happened, simply run the original setup code from the instructions again.

- If you're happy with the functions being nothing more than *short names* for the underlying `gh copilot` commands, you can update your `$PROFILE` as follows:

```
$GH_COPILOT_PROFILE = Join-Path (Split-Path $PROFILE) gh-copilot.ps1
@'
function ghce { gh copilot explain @args }
function ghcs { gh copilot suggest @args }
'@ >> (New-Item -FORCE $GH_COPILOT_PROFILE)
". $GH_COPILOT_PROFILE" >> $PROFILE
```

- If you want to use a Windows PowerShell-compatible version of the more sophisticated wrapper functions that `gh copilot alias -- pwsh` generates, based on the version current as of this writing:

```
$GH_COPILOT_PROFILE = Join-Path (Split-Path $PROFILE) gh-copilot.ps1
@'
function ghcs {
    # Debug support provided by common PowerShell function parameters, which is natively aliased as -d or -db
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.4#-debug
    param(
        [ValidateSet('gh', 'git', 'shell')]
        [Alias('t')]
        [String]$Target = 'shell',

        [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
        [string]$Prompt
    )
    # Create temporary file to store potential command user wants to execute when exiting
    $executeCommandFile = New-TemporaryFile

    # Store original value of GH_DEBUG environment variable
    $envGhDebug = $Env:GH_DEBUG

    if ($PSBoundParameters['Debug']) {
        $Env:GH_DEBUG = 'api'
    }

    try {
        gh copilot suggest -t $Target -s "$executeCommandFile" $Prompt

        # Execute command contained within temporary file if it is not empty
        if ($executeCommandFile.Length -gt 0) {
            # Extract command to execute from temporary file
            $executeCommand = (Get-Content -Path $executeCommandFile -Raw).Trim()

            # Insert command into PowerShell up/down arrow key history
            [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::AddToHistory($executeCommand)

            # Insert command into PowerShell history
            $now = Get-Date
            $executeCommandHistoryItem = [PSCustomObject]@{
                CommandLine        = $executeCommand
                ExecutionStatus    = [Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineState]::NotStarted
                StartExecutionTime = $now
                EndExecutionTime   = $now.AddSeconds(1)
            }
            Add-History -InputObject $executeCommandHistoryItem

            # Execute command
            Write-Host "`n"
            Invoke-Expression $executeCommand
      
        }
    }
    finally {
        # Clean up temporary file used to store potential command user wants to execute when exiting
        Remove-Item -Path $executeCommandFile
        # Restore GH_DEBUG environment variable to its original value
        $Env:GH_DEBUG = $envGhDebug
    }
}

function ghce {
    # Debug support provided by common PowerShell function parameters, which is natively aliased as -d or -db
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.4#-debug
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
        [string[]]$Prompt
    )
    # Store original value of GH_DEBUG environment variable
    $envGhDebug = $Env:GH_DEBUG
    if ($PSBoundParameters['Debug']) {
        $Env:GH_DEBUG = 'api'
    }

    try {
        gh copilot explain $Prompt
    }
    finally {
        # Restore GH_DEBUG environment variable to its original value
        $Env:GH_DEBUG = $envGhDebug
    }

}
'@ >> (New-Item -Force $GH_COPILOT_PROFILE)
". $GH_COPILOT_PROFILE" >> $PROFILE
```

The wrapper functions add support for debugging and, for `ghcs`, the ability to execute a suggested command and add it to PowerShell's command history.

---

###### General notes on profile loading:

- Note that installing [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)'s [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell), which comes with its own special-purpose shell - the PIC (PowerShell Integrated Console) - changes the file path that the [automatic `$PROFILE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#profile) points to, because the PIC uses a separate [profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) file.

  - Additionally, it is possible to *disable* profile loading in the PIC, so be sure that it is enabled: Open the Settings view (<kbd>Ctrl+,</kbd>) and navigate to `PowerShell: Enable Profile Loading`; searching for `profile load` should be enough to locate it.
- Therefore, installing the aliases from the PIC will *not* make them available in regular PowerShell console / Windows Terminal sessions, and also not in regular (non-PIC) PowerShell sessions in Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal.

  - To make all these environments *share* definitions, you have two options:

    - Either: Target `$PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts` rather than just `$PROFILE`; the path that the former points is loaded by *all* PowerShell environments run by the current user, irrespective of what application hosts them.
    - Or: Modify `$PROFILE` from a regular (non-PIC) session, then add the following to the PIC-specific `$PROFILE` file (open it for editing with `psedit $PROFILE`), which simply loads the the `.CurrentUserCurrentHost` profile that console-based (terminal-based) PowerShell sessions use:

      ```
      . ($PROFILE -replace '\.VSCode_', '.PowerShell_')
      ```
- After modifying a profile, you must either start a new PowerShell session or explicitly reload it, e.g. with `. $PROFILE`, using `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-).